# Allow expanding comments in Link Validation Review

Tags: feature-request, comments, review

The new Link Validation Review Queue (currently hidden by default) doesn't allow expanding the comments. I think this should be allowed as my first reaction when I see them is to expand the comments to check if someone has found the broken link and provided an alternative for it.

> [image: link validation review]