# Can we have a process that will let users know about link rot in their posts?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, broken-link

I noticed that [another user](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/13831057#13831057) had a post on Stack Overflow whose link had 404d and he never knew about it until I let him know about it.

I **know** that there is a broken link review queue under development somewhere, but my request is for something different.

Is there a way for us to have a monthly (or daily if possible) process that would let users know that a certain post (or posts) has a broken link in it and should be updated?

Comment: That used to exist, for a short while. There was a bot that went around and commented on broken links. Don't really know what happened to it.

Comment: Hmmm I see that @ShadowWizard but it seemed to be closed issue and not discussed at all. And also it was **before** the future _broken link review queue_.

Comment: While I agree with you, you didn't need to ping him to fix the issue. There is an edit button ;). Still this would be nice and it's obviously not that hard to query for question content and then iterate through them testing links. It would be a lot of data though.

Comment: Also @ShadowWizard I am not _entirely_ asking the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still active, but there used to be comments created by the community user on posts that contain broken links. I think this was only tested on meta and the tests have since ended...

The comment looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Not active anymore. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard - so `[status-was-planned-now-canned]`