# Let me post questions using Windows Live Writer

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I would like to create nice rich questions with images, but currently you have to put the image online somewhere and then add it to your post.

I would like to be able to create a question in Windows Live Writer and then post it to Stack Exchange. Then Live Writer would take care of uploading the images to an FTP site for you.

- Is this posible now?
- Does anyone like this idea?

Why: It is much easier for my to write my questions and answers in a fat client tool as it provides a much more robust experience. I can close it down and open it later. I can resize pictures so they take up less room, and I don't have to worry about my browser/computer crashing as it has auto saved to disk.

Comment: What problem exactly would this solve? Your laziness using image shack?

Comment: @Ladybug killer so you are happy with an inferior experiance? I sure you would be the firt one to compain if your email client did not support image pasting and auto saving. What about Word? Would you be happy if your word processor did not support images except to link to an external resource that you had to upload manualy?

Comment: @mrh: You have no idea how much I would appreciate when neither email clients nor word processors supported images.

Comment: I don't support this suggestion, but since when @Ladybug is laziness and the desire to have a simpler UI  a bad thing?

Comment: @Pekka: If you lower the threshold, it will be used more. Then we'll come back to the discussion Bobby linked to. Besides that, supporting this laziness with a better UI isn't worth the effort. At least not for the SOFU part of Stack Exchange. Don't know which proposals are out there, which need something like that.

Comment: @Pekka: Simpler is in my opinion easier to use...there is nothing easier to use then the SU-Textarea, you type, you post it. ;)

Comment: @Bobby I totally agree. But uploading images is a hassle, and could be made easier - if that's desired. I know some people don't like the feature at all.

Comment: I think I got a little flamed out on this one for asking to make things easyer! Not realy the responce I was hoping for :)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible at some point in the indeterminate future we might allow writes through our API.

But currently I am leaning away from this due to all the ways for low-quality, unknown content to enter the system this way.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible?

From a programming POV, most likely yes. *(Disclaimer: I'm always answering such questions with that...but I have to add "Depends on how much time you have")*

Also, the question is if Windows Live Writer does expose any APIs at all to the outside world (or the other way round, can use the APIs of other webservices). Also, what you're suggesting sounds more like a plugin for Live Writer then for SE.

> Does anyone like this idea?

Me not, nope, sorry. Answers should be kept simple, and I see no point in using a Third-Party-Tool to write 'simple text'. [Embedding images in an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48636/should-pictures-be-linked-to-or-embedded) seems like a very good [discussed topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9397/official-position-on-the-use-of-images-in-questions-and-answers).

**Edit:** As Pekka pointed out in the comments, it might be useful to have a simpler UI for posting and editing answers. The only point at which agree with this, is the point to save answers for the worst-case that the browser crashes. But you could also use a simple text-editor with a save-function for that (notepad, wordpad, gedit, jedit etc.).

There's a simple-to-use toolbox right above the textarea, that's all you should need. The focus should lay on the content, and not on the markup of it (imo).

**Edit2:** Uploading images shouldn't also be a problem, there are tons of Browser-AddOns and little helper tools out there for that.

Comment: It is much easyer for my to write my questions and answers in a fat client tool as it provides a much more robust experiance. I can close it down an open it later. I can resize pictures so they take up less room, and I don't have to worry about my browser/computer craching as it has auto saved to disk.

Comment: Is there even an accessable API for StackExchange?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this posible now?

Probably not. The HTML Live Writer produces is likely to be incompatible with Stack Overflow's own Markdown.

> Does anyone like this idea?

The automatic uploading of images is an interesting feature and it would be great to have that on SO proper. Other than that, I don't see much point in it - especially as Markdown's set of formatting possibilities is (intentionally) much more limited than HTML.

Comment: Windows Live Writers own standard markup is not disimilar to the Markdown set. In fact I did not see anything that WLW did that Markdown did not.

Comment: @mrhinsh image upload support is now in, see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/