# Is there a reason to limit Stack Exchange to synchronous & sequential image uploading?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, images, uploader

Sometimes, I have multiple small images to post along with my questions or answers. Currently, I have to upload these images one-by-one:

- Click on the image button in the toolbar
- Click on the "Choose file" button
- Select the image from disk
- Wait for the upload to complete

For the remaining images, I need to repeat the same process. Another problem is I need to wait for the completion of upload process. It blocks me from editing the post. :(
At least it should not prevent me from editing the text while uploading an image.

An example of the functionality I envision is Gmail's support for attachments. We can continue to edit emails while the image is being uploaded in the background. In my opinion, this would be a nice feature.

Comment: No, you can't request that `[feature-request]`s not be downvoted. Making the feature request is perfectly OK, though.

Comment: More is not always better.

Comment: Related: [Official position on the use of images in questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9397/official-position-on-the-use-of-images-in-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't go so far as to make it so you can upload multiple pictures simultaneously - very few posts should need more than an image or two, except on some specialty sites (probably photography, for instance).

Allowing the user to continue editing the post during image upload seems reasonable.

In the meantime, consider making your image file sizes smaller so they upload faster:

- Crop them to show only the relevant area
- Resize them so they are as low resolution as allows one to understand the issue
- Use JPG for photos and png or gif for screenshots and images with a lot of flat color

Comment: Yes, this pretty much captures my reservations about the feature. We don't want to encourage people to upload more than one (*maybe* two) images per post. But adding asynchronous uploading seems perfectly reasonable. (PS: Use PNG, not GIF.)