# Community ads posts are taken as "trivial" and converted to comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, advertising, convert-to-comment

It seems that the new feature ["Trivial answer converted to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/how-come-my-answer-appears-as-a-comment) interferes with the community ads. Any ad post which by design only contains a hyperlinked image is converted to a comment.

This happened on TeX.SX ([Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2011](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011)) to one user and also to me as 35k user and moderator.

A solution to this bug should be to disable this feature on questions tagged with [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads).

Comment: alternately, don't convert posts with images to a comment since images don't work in comments..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice spot; we're making sure images don't fall foul of this.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I think I see a hole in that solution...

Comment: @Won't: Simply checking on the `community-ads` tag as suggested would IMHO a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Comment: This isn't really a new problem, though. (Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9397/official-position-on-the-use-of-images-in-questions-and-answers/9407#9407)

Comment: The ["manual" for community ads](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011) requires "trivial" "answers" to be posted. I couldn't find any official announcement or description of the "Trivial answer converted to comment" feature. Also, in this specific case it is clearly a bug.

Comment: @Martin: I guess this is just a demonstration of the hole `:-)`

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I think answers should be more than "just an image".  99.99% of the time, an answer that contains only an image is not a satisfactory answer.  Except in some specific cases as you have mentioned, they should be allowed.  (btw, I wasn't telling you to RTFM, I was answering a hypothetical programming question)

Comment: yeah, but it isn't worth special-casing the ads; and an image *cannot* work in a comment; so leaving it "as is" is the sanest thing, IMO. At least then if it *is* an inappropriate image, other users can see immediately and kill it with fire.

Comment: @MarcGravell: [An image cannot work in a comment?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PNFxQ.png)  You can use the alt text, or if it is the standard alt text, just use the URL.

Comment: Ok; doesn't work *as well*...