# When should I include images in my questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, images

I'm planning to make a post about a quite "visual" project on SO to ask for advice, and I'll probably need to include a few images in the post to make my point go through.

I was wondering if it's generally a good or a bad practice to include several images in a post. I've rarely seen posts with images, which is why I'm asking myself this. Is there a size limit on the posts?

Generally, is it a better practice to make an elaborate but precise post for a question, or try to keep it to the minimum? I'm still pretty new to the community, so I want to make sure I'm following the standards.

Comment: Ask for advice? What does that mean? Sounds a bit "not constructive" to me.

Comment: I'm just asking for standards...

Comment: Related question: [Official position on the use of images in questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9397)

Comment: Whenever they have freehand circles in them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use images if, and *only* if, they help describe the problem better than text can and thus make answering the question easier.

In general, you should use images for graphics-related issues, and only when it can't be adequately described with text.

Comment: Yes I think in case of image processing like what I'm looking for, that's hard to describe without images :)

Comment: If you cannot describe it, then future visitors with the same problem cannot find it using a search engine, and then your question might be too localized for these sites, @linker. (Remember these sites are not some help forum, but [*libraries* of high quality canonical questions and their answers](http://stackexchange.com/about/).)