# Do I include way more images in my posts than others, (or do I just post way more)? Can SEDE address this?

Tags: support, data-explorer, images

The inclusion of images in posts has up and down sides. They convey information and sometimes the question is specifically about the image. At the same time they also consume bandwidth, make for slow page loading, cost real money for much of the world on mobile data plans and actually distract/bother some users<sup>1</sup>. Further, some users access SE through screen readers and images without alt texts leave the reader needlessly wondering "what am I missing" and potentially feeling somewhat excluded.

I post a lot and I find images more than helpful. For me once a post is associated with an image in my head, my recollection of the post later comes via memory of the image, as well as some keywords which may not actually be in the post.

Nonetheless it is a fair question to ask, based on recent criticism of me elsewhere, and I'd like to know if I'm over-imaging my posts in an inordinate way, or if that's just a perception because I post a lot.

**Question:** Can SEDE address whether I include way more images in my posts than others?

One way to go about checking this would be to scan text for

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxxxx.xxx 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxxxxx.xxx  (display size modifier)
```

in all posts since a given user has joined (try to avoid bias due to overall increase of images with time as the bandwidth of everything has increased). Ideally it would be broken down by `xxxxx.xxx` vs `xxxxxm.xxx` + `xxxxxs.xxx` to demonstrate a user's attempt to [minimize the displayed size and page download speed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25052/295232) by using one of imgur's features.

Of course a text search would be complicated by the fact that in-line format has two copies, as does separate lines for sized and unsized:

default

```
[![an image][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxxxx.jpg
```

versus inline (which is very, very helpful when re-block-quoting a bit of a post in a new post)

```
[![an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxxxx.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxxxx.jpg)
```

versus default with two sizes

```
[![an image][2]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxxxx.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxxxxm.jpg
```

So hopefully, SEDE provides a better way to count them?

---

<sup>1</sup>ref: personal communication. A question about a potential future "toggle images on/off" option for those challenged by visual overloading might (or might not) be forthcoming.

---

What one might do with such data:

[image: images per post (simulation)]

Potentially related (and fairly non committal):

- [Knowing Your Limits: What is the maximum length of a question title, post, image and links used?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176445/303080)
- [When should I include images in my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129382/303080)

Comment: I think it's easier than you think to evaluate this in SEDE because you can search the rendered view for `<img`.

Comment: 1. I don’t think you can assume that using more images than other users means you post too many. 2. As long as you are using good, descriptive alt text (so that those that aren’t seeing the image get the same information) you aren’t excluding anyone. (If the image is already described in the regular text, leave it blank instead of being redundant.)

Comment: Related (canonical): *[Why should I not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)*

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum it's always good to keep track of canonical questions and their answers! Just for the record, while I do for example occasionally include screenshots of things like NASA PowerPoint slides for context when asking about their content, I also include the question-related text as text and describe any salient images on those slides.

Answer (score 6):

[Yes, you do, at least on Astronomy.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/astronomy/query/1567898/analysis-of-number-of-images-per-post?MaximumNumberOfImages=10&UserId=7982#graph) but I agree with @BSMP in the comments that it does not need to be a problem, especially if you use alt text (which I regularly forget, I'll admit). Most of the times, a picture says more than a thousand words. So, instead of showing raw data here, I'm giving you a line chart (SEDE doesn't support bar charts):

[image: graph showing @uhoh's images per post vs. the community average on Astronomy.SE; @uhoh's frequencies are significantly higher except for 0 images]

I'm not accounting for size modifiers: sometimes, images are already small and don't *need* such a modifier.

Comment: Nice that this one user can create such a smooth distribution.